# HTML dropdown box for selectable IP address with PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a task where the user will input a network address (i.e. 192.168.1.0) and a subnet mask/cidr (255.255.255.0 or /24), and the script will display the gateway (first available IP) then an HTML dropdown box will contain all available IPs in the range. This will then input into the SQL database that tracks all used/unavailable IP addresses.

The first page where the user inputs the ip/subnet are pretty basic

```
<form method='POST' action='iprange.php'>
Network Address<br /><input type='text' name='netaddress' value=''><br />
Subnet Mask<br />
<select name='subnet'>
<option value='24'>255.255.255.0 or /24</option>
<option value='24'>255.255.255.128 or /25</option>
<option value='24'>255.255.255.192 or /26</option>
<option value='24'>255.255.255.224 or /27</option>
</select>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

and currently have another script that I have found that starts to do this as shown below:

```
<?php

function getIpRange(  $cidr) {

    list($ip, $mask) = explode('/', $cidr);

    $netaddress = $_POST["netaddress"];
    $subnet = $_POST["subnet"];
    $maskBinStr =str_repeat("1", $mask ) . str_repeat("0", 32-$mask );      //net mask binary string
    $inverseMaskBinStr = str_repeat("0", $mask ) . str_repeat("1",  32-$mask ); //inverse mask

    $ipLong = ip2long( $ip );
    $ipMaskLong = bindec( $maskBinStr );
    $inverseIpMaskLong = bindec( $inverseMaskBinStr );
    $netWork = $ipLong & $ipMaskLong; 

    $start = $netWork+2;//ignore network ID and Gateway(eg: 192.168.1.0)

    $end = ($netWork | $inverseIpMaskLong) -1 ; //ignore brocast IP(eg: 192.168.1.255)
    return array('firstIP' => $start, 'lastIP' => $end );
}

function getEachIpInRange ( $cidr) {
    $ips = array();
    $range = getIpRange($cidr);
    for ($ip = $range['firstIP']; $ip <= $range['lastIP']; $ip++) {
        $ips[] = long2ip($ip);
    }
    return $ips;
}

$cidr = $netaddress'/'$subnet; // max. 30 ips
print_r(getEachIpInRange ( $cidr));


/* output: 
Array                                                                 
(                                                                     
    [0] => 172.16.0.1                                                 
    [1] => 172.16.0.2
    [2] => 172.16.0.3
    ...
    [27] => 172.16.0.28                                               
    [28] => 172.16.0.29                                               
    [29] => 172.16.0.30
) 
*/
```

I do not need help putting this into the SQL database, but getting the one IP displayed as the gateway, then putting the rest into a drop down box is where I am having issues. I have worked with this code and can't seem to get it to do what I need. I have worked with PHP/HTML for a while, but not at this level.

I am not too attached to any of this code but am currently at a loss. Thank you for any help on this.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear .... do you have code that is putting the options into a dropdown? have you made an attempt at it?  If so, show that, and share the specific area where you're having issues....

Comment: As mentioned "..but getting the one IP displayed as the gateway, then putting the rest into a drop down box is where I am having issues". I have tired multiple attempts in several different areas over the last three hours and can't get the first IP address in the range to be displayed (ex, echo) then the rest of the range being put into a drop down box so the user can select which they want.

Comment: Again: Show your code attempts _for that part_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have to use ajax or not. For the dropdown you can do something like:

```
<?php
$ipList= getEachIpInRange( $cidr);
?>
<select name="ips">
<?php foreach($ipList as $ip): ?>
    <option value=<?php echo $ip?>><?php echo $ip?></option>
<?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

Comment: No, not planning on using ajax. I will check this out.

Comment: That didn't work. I put it in exactly like you had it, and tried tweaking it but couldn't get it to show the dropdown let alone having it populated.

Comment: @MicahW. Check that I edited and fixed the getEachIpInRange call (no $ before it). do you get the ip list after calling getEachIpInRange( $cidr)? (try a print_r($ipList) after the call)

Comment: Awesome. Pasted just like you have it, and it works! Thank you so much!